# Windows Authentication for Single Page in CMS site

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, sitecore

I am running into a situation and Need some help on this.
I have a CMS site out of which 2 pages in seperate folder alone are admin pages for administrative purposes. They need windows Authentication to be enabled. This is what i did.
In IIS, i enabled Anonymous authentication for the whole site and disabled windows authentication.
I enabled Windows Authentication only for the particular folder and gave read access to that folder for a user.
Everything worked fine. When the pop up opens and i give my windows credentials and it is authenticated, using my .net Application when i try to see `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` I get "`sitecore\Admin`" rather than getting my current windows user id. Any help on this would be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Windows Authentication on the folder through IIS by itself will only protect the folder, and will not tie into the Sitecore membership provider so the current user's identity does not get set. You will have to do that part by yourself on your custom administration pages when the page loads.

You can do that by getting the username from the `LOGON_USER` server variable like this:

```
var username = Context.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
```

You can then change the current user's identity by calling the `Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login` method like so:

```
var success = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(userName, false);
if (!success)
{
    // Handle login failure.
}
```